# Prism MVVM - Showing Pop up window from viewmodel on a button click command in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a datagrid in my view(UserControl) in which I have a button, The requirement is to show a window on click of that button. I achieved it by creating an object for the window and calling it's show method and yes it's a wrong way, So, I want a standard way of achieving it.

I'm using Prism framework, So I mapped the window view with Window viewmodel using ViewModelLocationProvider in the windowviewmodel.

```
var table = new Window();

table.Content = new windowViewModel();

table.Show();
```

This is the code I implemented in the main viewmodel on click of the button.

It is actually opening a window, but, view is not getting loaded on the window.

Comment: Why not use the `IDialogService` (new in version 7)

Comment: Can you please help me on how to use IDialogService!

Comment: look at the answer I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IDialogService` Introduced in Prism 7

first the dialog view or ViewModel needs to implement the `IDialogAware` interface  like this:

```
   class PopupViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
   {
          public string Title => "Popup";
          public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

    public bool CanCloseDialog()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnDialogClosed()
    {
    }
    public DelegateCommand OkCommand => new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
        //you can also pass any parameters you want to back pass to the caller
        RequestClose.Invoke(new DialogResult(ButtonResult.OK)); 
    });

    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
       //here you get the parameters you passed;
    }
  }
```

then you need to register your view like this

```
  containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<Views.Popup>();
```

to use you inject into your ViewModel the `IDialogService` and call it

```
       this.dialogService.ShowDialog(nameof(Views.Popup), dialogParmaters, (result)=> 
      {
              if(result.Result == ButtonResult.OK)
              {
              }
      });
```

you can also register your custom window if you want the window needs to implement `IDialogWindow`

```
         containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyDialogWindow>();
```

Comment: Will It open multiple windows, I should also restrict opening of window when a window is already opened.

Comment: depends what you call `Show` or `ShowDialog`

Answer (score 1):

First, you want the view model to be the `DataContext` (the `Content` is in fact the view). I'd advise againt the `ViewModelLocator` here, because it makes it impossible to pass parameters to the new window. Probably, you want to show different content depending on which row you click the button in.

```
new Window { DataContext = new WindowViewModel( myRow ) }.Show();
```

Second, there's nothing wrong with this approach but for one minor remark: put the code that shows the window in a service. You want to unittest your view models and that doesn't go well with opening real windows.

```
public interface IWindowService
{
    void ShowWindow( SomeParameter parameter );
}
```

If you inject that into your view model, you can still test it (verify that `ShowWindow` is called).

Third, remove calls to new and replace them with calls to injected factories.

```
var viewModel = _viewModelFactory.Create( "some parameter" );
```

is a lot nicer than

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel( "some parameter", new ADependency( new OtherDependency(), new SomeService() );
```

not to speak of the difficulties if singletons are involved.